# How to determine if there is only one value versus multiple?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that checks a column of values and if there is a value, puts those values in a comma delimited string. My question is, if there is only one in the column list i'm checking, how can i exclude the formula from outputting a value unless there is multiple values?

```
=BI3801&IF(BI3802<>"",", "&BI3802,"")&IF(BI3803<>"",", "&BI3803,"")&IF(BI3804<>"",", "&BI3804,"")
```

outputs if there are values: "value1, value2"

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA?  Your question doesn't seem to be about programming.

Comment: @rory.ap it's about excel formula.

Comment: Excel formulas aren't about programming. This question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow; maybe there's a forum or Q & A site dedicated to MS Office Apps?  in fact, I know there are some.  Just google it.

Comment: @rory.ap why don't you get off this thread if you don't want to contribute to helping. If this doesn't belong on stack overflow why are there tons of issues relating to formulas ect?

Comment: You're right.  My bad.  It's one of those gray areas but the consensus seems to be that Excel formulas are on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i took a range C1 and put in formula `=CountBlank(A1:A5)` which counts all the blank and then in my original formula, `=IF(C1<4, myCommaDelimitedFormula, "")`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in another `IF` statement. Example with column **A**

```
=IF(COUNTA(A:A)>1,your_formula,"")
```

**UPDATE**

You might find that `VBA` will serve you better here. This function will take a column and return a comma delimited list as long as there are two or more non-zero values

Paste this into a new module in the VBA editor

```
Function CommaDelim(rng As Range)
    Dim outputStr As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim r2 As Range

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "<>0") < 2 Then
        CommaDelim = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> 0 Then
            outputStr = outputStr & r.Value & ","
        End If
    Next r
    outputStr = Left(outputStr, Len(outputStr) - 1)

    CommaDelim = outputStr
End Function
```

Then on the worksheet you can use the function like this:

```
=CommaDelim(A1:A5)
```

[image]

Comment: the values are not really empty, they are just blank because in those column ranges, they are formula calculating for other reasons.

Comment: this actually returns me duplicates if lets say i have two values in the list and the rest are blank but not empty values. Plus i can't have this is a module, the sheet will be imported to another workbook therefore loses the function.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to include a sample of your data -- because I tested this with my own dummy data and it worked just fine

Comment: put this in your other range list column =IF(A3= "---","", A3) and check that list.

Comment: I included an image of how this is intended to work. How does our data differ?

Comment: put this in your column B1: =IF(A1= "---","", A1) and so forth all the way to B5, then check your column B using your function. CommaDelima(B1:B5) make sure you have "---" in A2,A3

Comment: So it's including the 0's as well?

Comment: yes, thats why i said, it's blank but not empty, since on mine, it shows blank instead of 0 if you use "---" in column A in place of blanks.

Comment: Ah, i see - try the code now. If that answers your question please select the tick mark to the left of this answer

Comment: That don't work, it adds too many comma between, I've solved the problem already, i took a range C1 and put in formula =CountBlank(A1:A5) which counts all the blank and then in my original formula, =IF(C1<4, myCommaDelimitedFormula, "")